# How to recode and encode a country pair variable in R

Tags: r

I am trying to recode a variable for country pairs, e.g. an exporter EFG and an importeur ISR equals the country pair EFGISR. I need these pairs for a panel data analysis and therefore these country pairs have to be set to numeric variables. I am familiar to the as.numeric command, however recoding these variables back to the format seems to be a tough job. Do you guys know a better way to code it or a way to use the factor variable as a referene for a recode call ? I will have to use the plm package and the command make.pballanced().

Cheers and I would really appreciate your help!

edit:

```
idvar <- c(BRAWLD, BRAALB, BRADZA, BRAARG, BRAAUS, BRAAUT, BRABHR, BRAARM)

as.numeric(idvar)
[1] 108   2  30   5   7   8  12   6   9  15  11  17  23  19

as.factor(idvar)
[1] 108   2  30   5   7   8  12   6   9  15  11  17  23  19
```

This is the part where I would like to have again

```
idvar
BRAWLD, BRAALB, BRADZA, BRAARG, BRAAUS, BRAAUT, BRABHR, BRAARM
```

I am Heading my dataset here:

```
year    exp exp_iso                  imp imp_iso       nw       tv     nw_c nw_dc     tv_c tv_dc tv_total nw_total id_var
1996-BRAARE 1996 Brazil     BRA United Arab Emirates     ARE   563812  1245639   563812     0  1245639     0  1245639   563812 BRAARE
1996-BRAARG 1996 Brazil     BRA            Argentina     ARG 34006800 77508984 34006800     0 77508984     0 77508984 34006800 BRAARG
1996-BRAARM 1996 Brazil     BRA              Armenia     ARM    38398   70656    38398     0    70656     0    70656    38398 BRAARM
1996-BRAAUS 1996 Brazil     BRA            Australia     AUS  3213000  7864554  3213000     0  7864554     0  7864554  3213000 BRAAUS
1996-BRAAUT 1996 Brazil     BRA              Austria     AUT 11189578 25442560 11189578     0 25442560     0 25442560 11189578 BRAAUT
1996-BRABEL 1996 Brazil     BRA              Belgium     BEL 41944172 93179224 41944172     0 93179224     0 93179224 41944172 BRABEL
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Nikolai KI, you need to provide a small example. If you can't, add some pseudo code of what you want to accomplish, along with sample data.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I don't see any "country pair" data. Are the entries in `idvar` your country pairs? Or single country IDs? How do you get paired data? Does the order matter? What do you mean by "recoding these variables back to the format"? Could you please clearly state what your input (sample) data and expected output is.

Comment: ok, i see "braaus" should be brazil-australia, you then combine your objects, but where do  your objects come from? or what you want to do is exclusive for the characters "bra" and "aus"

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. I have the variables 

exp_iso, contatining the iso3 codes of countries as BRA stands for Brazil and the correspoding imp_iso, like AUS for Austria. I paste them to a new variable called ID-Var, needed for a panel data analyses to analyse the relationship between importeurs and exporteurs. The idvar variable contains then the relationship, as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I found an appealing solution to the problem. Using the package countryodes provides a formula with which I could paste the charachter country codes as numeric codes using the countrycode = "iso3n".